# Change only the font of numerics/numbers in Word 2007

Tags: fonts, microsoft-word-2007

How do I change the font used by numbers, or numerics, in a Word 2007 document?

For the rest of the document, they would be using another font for the letters and such, but I would like the numbers to be in a different font altogether.

If this is possible, how do I set it?

Comment: You mean you want to change the font of all the numbers but not of all the other characters?

Comment: This is specific for 2007, however, see http://superuser.com/questions/1081473/different-fonts-mash-up-for-text-and-numbers/1081507#1081507 for another solution

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "set" this, but you can use find and replace to apply a character style (or font directly) on what is matched.

Select the "More>>" button to see the option to search with wildcards, then use `([0-9]{1,})` to find sequences of 1 or more digits (see the help for more details on wildcard patterns). Use `\1` in the replacement to just keep the same text.

Under the replace group in the dialogue there is a "format" button, use this to select the format you want to apply.