# Different Fonts Mash-up for text and numbers

Tags: fonts, microsoft-word-2013

I want to use a font i.e. `Candara` for *text* and at the same time, I want to use some other font for *numbers* in the *text* because the *number* style in the font `Candara` is somehow disturbing (at least for me). I don't want to change fonts again and again while writing *text* and *numbers*.

Is it possible to use `Candara` font for *text* and some other font for *numbers* simultaneously (with out changing font again and again).

Comment: Related http://superuser.com/questions/128719/change-only-the-font-of-numerics-numbers-in-word-2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with VBa. Depending on the size of your file (how many words you have) it may be slow.

It also assumes that you only use 2 fonts. If you use other fonts, it will overwrite them!!

It's VBa so remember, save it first to create a back up (there is no undo)

```
Sub updateFont()

Dim doc As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument
Dim i As Integer    
For i = 1 To doc.Range.Characters.Count

     If IsNumeric(doc.Range.Characters(i)) Then
        doc.Range.Characters(i).Font.Name = "Algerian"
        Else
        doc.Range.Characters(i).Font.Name = "Verdana"
     End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Screenshot before (using an italic font)
[image]

and after

[image]

[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)

Comment: @Dave--"Variable not defined" error raised while compiling your code.

Comment: But i think `Dim i As Integer` is missing in your code as I made this change and it worked for me then.

Comment: I have added a new button for this macro to use for all documents. But I can't see that button, where will I find it ?

Comment: I'm unable to use macro for other new documents. Why is it so whereas I saved that macro function for all documents. Now here is error that macro security disabled whereas I enabled all macros therefore

Comment: Each time in each document will I need to run macro code in macro editor ?

Comment: If I need to run this macro code each time for each new document, then what's the use of creating a button for macro or macro keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I know you didn't suggest but I saw from somewhere else anyhow I just want to use this macro for each new document without running macro code again and again.

Comment: These links are not much relevant as 1st is related to excel and other is something else. I'm going to take a new question.